# How to find calling class for an Activity in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have my project in debug mode, and I placed a break point within Activity1. . However, when the execution of the project halts at this break point, I need to find out which Activity or class called Activity1.

I tried looking through [Android studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) and I did not find away how.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do this in terms of the Android SDK. You are welcome to do something yourself to your `Intent` to help distinguish them, such as putting an extra on the `Intent` that indicates who called `startActivity()`. Then, you can look at the `Intent` that `Activity1` gets via `getIntent()`, to determine which activity started it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your only want to know the activities you are viewing, you could easily do it by viewing Logcat. Open the logcat window (AndroidMonitor -> logcat)

Search for ActivityManager

You wull get the below logs

> 07-19 15:42:04.064 606-632/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed
>   com.android.dialer/.**DialtactsActivity:** +674ms

In this case I launched the phone application.

But if you simple want to put some piece of code which executes only if this activity is launched from a particular place then you can do something like this.

Put this code when you launch the activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);
intent.putExtra("ENABLE_XXX_CODE", true);
```

In the activity where you want to put enable some logic for this particular flow :

```
boolean isEnabled = savedInstanceState.getString("ENABLE_XXX_CODE");  
if(isEnabled)
{
//Your logic goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it by default and here is why:

Android aims for a loosely coupled app lifecycle, which means that every `Activity`, `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` lives on its own. They can be started by an `Intent`, which is sent from `Context` into the system architecture and then starts the new component. Therefore, you will not see the source of the `Intent` in the break-point stacktrace, just some generic system calls.

In order to see what invoked the `Activity`, you will need to add some extra data to the invoking `Intent`. You do it like this:

```
intent.putExtra("SOME_KEY", someValue);
```

And then in `onCreate()` you read it like this:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    String source = savedInstanceState.getString("SOME_KEY");   
}
```

If the sender stated the source value, you will have it here :-)

As a side note, you will usually not want to know what started the `Activity`. The only real-life case where the above code would be used is the situation where you want some params passed to the `Activity` to configure it. Apart from that, every `Activity` is and should be a separate entity :-)